# Datagram receive method blocked due to timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, timeout

I am working on a client-server project that sends/receives using UDP socket which handles packet drop and timeouts. Since the receive method is blocked every time the packet is lost (if timeout occurs), i need to find a way to kill the thread where the receive socket is blocked. The problem is, it is not throwing any exception so have no idea how to kill the thread.I want to terminate the thread so that i can restart again the next attempt.

Answer (score 1):

> need a way to kill the thread

No you don't.

You need a way to *detect the timeout.*

Set a read timeout, with `setSoTimeout()`, and catch `SocketTimeoutException` when it triggers.

Comment: Does it correspond to closing the socket in case i incur timeout? could u tell me if its specially used for this purpose of blocking input? since i am sending chunks of data is it  possible to reset if i received the packet successfully.

Comment: It works fine with sockettimeout but will it work on all the cases. Cases in the sense that if i start using window size and all, is it even possible to manage timer only by throwing this exception. which is the better way Threads or sockettimoutexception if i am setting up only one client and server?

Comment: (A) The socket is not closed when you get a timeout exception. (B) If you got some data you didn't get a timeout. A read timeout starts when you enter a read method. You don't need to reset it, unless you want to change the value. (C) A timeout is a timeout. It will work in all cases of timeout. (D) Your question about 'manag[ing] the timer by throwing this exception' doesn't make any sense to me. (E) Surely it is obvious that a timeout and a catch is considerably simpler than two threads?

Comment: Thank you. I am able to catch the exception as receive input is blocked by catching the timeoutexception.But i feel it would be better if i use threads but i do not know how to stop the currently executing thread. Because by socket exception timeout happens only when the packet/ACK is lost so i could not maintain balanced timeout to all the packets (if success-> does not wait, want to give a time slot to receive some more extra packet within that time. Hence it would be really useful if u give me a hint on how to stop the Thread that is currently running a process

Comment: And why thread.stop( ) is deprecated as it may be useful in releasing threads as a result of such blocks?